# Close dropdowns by clicking outside of them with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I don't quite understand why my script does not working:

jQuery:

```
$(".dropdown-category").click(function() {
$(".dropdown a").removeClass("clicked");
$(".dropdown a").children("span").removeClass("clicked");
$(".dropdown-arrow").toggleClass("open");
$(".dropdown").toggleClass("open");
});

$(".dropdown a").click(function() {
$(".dropdown a").removeClass("clicked");
$(".dropdown a").children("span").removeClass("clicked");
$(this).toggleClass("clicked");  $(this).children("span").toggleClass("clicked");
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown-category">
<p>Categories</p>
<img src="images/dropdown-arrow.svg" alt="" class="dropdown-arrow">
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
<a href="#" id="link">Link
  <span></span>
</a>
<a href="#" id="link">Link
  <span></span>
</a>
<a href="#" id="link">Link
  <span></span>
</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown-category {
 color: #627184;
 font-size: 15px;
 background: #fff;
 padding: 14.5px 25px;
 box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(230, 235, 241, 0.9);
 border-radius: 20px;
 display: inline-block;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: transform 0.2s ease, box-shadow 0.2s ease, color 0.2s ease;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 margin-top: 20px;
}

.dropdown-category:hover {
 box-shadow:0px 10px 30px rgba(116,116,116,0.15);
}
```

When I push outside, he doesn't want to close it. only when I press the button? I don't know where my mistake is

Comment: It's hard to tell what do you mean by "outside". Outside the Categories or the dropdown? Could you add some css to make that and the behavior you want clear?

Comment: Hi, the dropdown menu opens and closes by clicking on the "dropdown-category" button, I want it to be able to close if I click somewhere outside the container.